# Google Chrome, Edge throwing warning <link rel=preload> uses an unsupported `as` value for document

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, microsoft-edge

I am using  <[link rel=preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload)> to preload an iframe.

e.g. `<link rel="preload" href="https://example.com" as="document">`

But Chrome and Edge giving me warning as `<link rel=preload> uses an unsupported 'as' value`. Also cannot see any document request for https://example.com in Network tab.

Tried to remove the `as` attribute but again it is throwing `<link rel=preload> must have a valid 'as' value` warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said that in the document you mentioned. The `as="document"` is not support in Chrome or Edge. Something like this below.

[image]
In this case,I think you have to modify your code to match browser compatibility. Or switch the browser which support this attribute.